# Check which of the children elements was clicked

Tags: jquery

I want to verify which of the ".quality" elements was clicked

```
$("#content").on('click', ".delinquent > .quality", function(){
    selected = this;
    $(".quality", $(selected).parent()).each(function(){
        if (selected == this){
            $(this).toggleClass("selected", true);
            $(this).toggleClass("unselected", false);
        }else{
            $(this).toggleClass("selected", false);
            $(this).toggleClass("unselected", true);
        }
    });
})
```

this was the code I tried to use, but it doesn't seem that it works, since all of the .quality spans had the .selected class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. You want to apply selected class on the quality item clicked and apply unselected class on the rest of the quality items. Assuming that all the `.quality` elements are siblings of each other you can simplify your code like this.

```
$("#content").on('click', ".delinquent > .quality", function(){
    $(this)
      //Add selected class to the current item clicked
      .removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected')
      //Find all the siblings and add unselected class
      .siblings().removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Event Delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) is a wonderful thing in Javascript.

The event object contains a [`target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/), which is the element that triggered the event.  You can access it like so:

```
$("#content").on('click', ".delinquent > .quality", function (e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```